# Limit Taxonomy Output in Conditional Statement

Tags: php, functions, terms

I am trying to limit the amount of category tags I output to 5 as well as append a "..." to the end of any items where the output was limited. I've got it mostly working except I can't figure out how to only echo the first 5 tags.

I should mention I only want this to take place on a particular page, but the code I am working with is stored in the functions file but is called by the page in question.

The ideal output would look like this:

**Item 1**:
tag 1, tag 2, tag 3

**Item 2**:
tag 1, tag 2, tag 3, tag 4, tag 5...

This is the code I have so far. I think I need to use `array_splice` but am not sure how to implement it.

```
if ( $type === 'portfolio' ) {
            $terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'royal_portfolio_cats', '', $separator );
            $term_array = explode(',',$terms);
            $count = sizeof($term_array);               
            if ($count <= 5) {
                echo $terms;
            }
            elseif ($count > 5) {

                $limit_terms = //Do something to output only the first 5 terms with comma separators

                echo $limit_terms."...";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try this `if ( $limit = array_slice($term_array, 0, $max = 5) ) { echo implode( ", ", $limit ); if ( count( $terms ) > $max ) { echo " ..."; } }` after `$term_array`

Comment: That worked! Except I had to use `$term_array` instead of `if ( count( $terms ) > $max ) { echo " ..."; }`

Comment: Oops. Forgot that one ;)

Comment: You could also filter on `term_links-royal_portfolio_cats` which passes an array to it - but it doesn't pass args so you don't have access to `before` or `after` in order to add the ellipsis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Samuel Elh](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/70833/samuel-elh) correctly answered this.

```
    if ( $type === 'portfolio' ) {
            $terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'royal_portfolio_cats', '', $separator );
            $term_array = explode(',',$terms);

            if ( $limit = array_slice($term_array, 0, $max = 5) ) { 
                echo implode( ", ", $limit ); 
                if ( count( $term_array ) > $max ) { 
                    echo "..."; 
                } 
            };

        }
```